# Issue while configuring Hadoop 2.6.0 in Eclipse on Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I've been trying to configure Hadoop 2.6.0 in Eclipse on Windows using this tutorial - http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/47/build-install-configure-eclipse-plugin-apache-hadoop

I'm able to build Hadoop 2.6.0 plugin jar for Eclipse. My Hadoop cluster daemons are up and running on Windows. But when I try to connect eclipse to HDFS as per the tutorial nothing shows up.

[image]

I've also tried with Map/Reduce(V2) Master Port - 50070(namenode https port)  and DFS Master Port - 8020(fs port) but no luck.

Any advise would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by running Eclipse as an administrator. Hadoop location would show '0' if there is no data in HDFS. At first instance it looks like, eclipse is not able to connect to HDFS though.